# select node that does not contain any of given nodes

Tags: php, xml, xpath

This is the XML I am working on

```
<root>
<person>
<name>Bob</name>
<age>23</age>
</person>
<person>
<name>Dina</name>
<age>19</age>
</person>
<person>
<name>John</name>
<age>31</age>
</person>
<person>
<name>Tim</name>
</person>
</root>
```

Here I can get all the person name that has age attribute with

```
/person[age]/name
```

This will select Bob, Dina and John

But How do I select Tim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/root/person[not(age)]/name
```

That should work.

Comment: Gotcha! It worked. Do you know any good reference of xpath function without W3.org?

Comment: Great :)  I've generally used w3 or w3schools in the past sorry, I don't know of another resource.

Comment: Have a look at [these lecture slides](https://svn.uni-konstanz.de/dbis/xml_w12/pub/04%20XPath.pdf), took that course myself some years ago and still regard it best XPath ressource I know apart from being split over multiple slides. Somebody should form a cheat sheet out of it. ;)

Comment: @JensErat: Nice PDF, just grabbed it. -- -at-OP: There is also the W3C spec of Xpath 1.0 I often read through http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/ until I understood it (maybe a stony road, but in the end I double checked with it most often), and there is https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPath